# How to make below shown picture like style using TouchableNativeFeedback in React Native?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

**I am attaching two images, one showing the current view and other showing the view that i want it to be.**

[image: This is my Current View]

[image: This View i want to implement]

You can see in the above images, in the first image, the highlighted area is a rectangle whereas in the second one, it is a rounded rectangle.
I want to achieve second style , but i am not able to do.

**The highlighted area is actually the result of TouchableNativeFeedback Component in React Native**

Please guide me to achieve this

**Code snippet is mentioned below :-**

```
<View style={styles.chatDetailsScreenActionBar}>
   <View style={styles.chatDetailsScreenBackButtonView}>
       <TouchableNativeFeedback>
           <View style={styles.chatDetailsScreenBackButton}>
               <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back" size={30} color="white" />
               <Image source={{ uri: this.state.selectedChat.chat_thumbnail }} 
                          style={styles.chatDetailsScreenBackButtonImage} />
           </View>
       </TouchableNativeFeedback>
   </View>
</View>
```

**Styles code for above Layout :-**

```
chatDetailsScreenActionBar: {
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#006156',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    chatDetailsScreenBackButtonView: {
        height: 55,
        width: 70,
        borderRadius: 24
    },
    chatDetailsScreenBackButton: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: "100%"
    },
    chatDetailsScreenBackButtonImage: {
        height: 36,
        width: 36,
        borderRadius: 18
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the 'TouchableNativeFeedback' component style { borderRadius: 1000 }

Comment: You need to give 'borderRadius' style to make corners rounded. Just figure out which component is the one doing that and give him that styling. If you'll post code it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: Hey, i added the code snippet, once check it please

Comment: add 'borderRadius: 100' to "chatDetailsScreenActionBar" styles

Comment: "chatDetailsScreenActionBar" is the whole rectangle , so it should no affect anything.
But i tried this also, nothing changed

Comment: try to give them all

Answer (score 0):

try this :
`<TouchableNativeFeedback style={styles.TNF} > '...your code' </TouchableNativeFeedback>`

`TNF:{ width: ... , height: ... , backgroundColor:'#...' , borderRadius:50}`

Comment: yes, usually borderRadius is the choice for such cases, but in this case, it is not working.